# My resource pack won't show up in client

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

[The Resource Pack](http://www.mediafire.com/file/4ed668ze4ucd1f2/Germensa's_BOOMPACK.zip) is in the folder but when I open the client and go to resource packs it isnt there. Unless I click the open folder option and see it in there but still not in my client.

I got some of this resource pack from another one and made sure I didn't mess anything up, the mcmeta is there, and so are my assets, all I did was edit the swords to make it look more silly and put it back in place of the old swords.

Comment: No, you have not tried everything. Otherwise it would work. So in general: Give details to what you have tried.

Comment: If we don't know what you've tried, we're going to have an extremely hard time helping you. Saying you've tried everything is extremely unhelpful.

Answer (score 5):

In your [pack.mcmeta](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Creating_a_resource_pack#pack.mcmeta), description value is not contained in quotation marks.

Here is yours currently:

```
{
  "pack": {
    "pack_format": 1,
    "description": ÒYOU ALL UGLYÒ
  }
}
```

Here is what it needs to be in order to work:

```
{
  "pack": {
    "pack_format": 1,
    "description": "ÒYOU ALL UGLYÒ"
  }
}
```

Another thing, you have used a special character in that description(`Ò`).  That does not show up correctly in minecraft:

[image: Resource pack]

If you do want that to show up correctly, pack.mcmeta has to use unicode:

```
{
  "pack": {
    "pack_format": 1,
    "description": "\u00D2YOU ALL UGLY\u00D2"
  }
}
```

Here is the result:
[image: Pack 2]

Also just to note, pack_format 1 is for versions 1.6-1.8.  (2 is 1.9-1.10, 3 is 1.11-1.12, and 4 is 1.13) This is why it shows up with a red color in my resource pack list in my first image.

---

[Here is a link](http://www.mediafire.com/file/msr85s7blvcgcn2/Germensa%27s%20BOOMPACK.zip) to a modified version of the pack which loads successfully for me.  Looks good:

[image: Pack]

Answer (score 0):

Inside that zip file, you're supposed to have the filesystem like this:

```
{TEXTURE PACK NAME}/assets/minecraft/{fonts/textures/stuff here}
```

So [unzip this file](http://www.mediafire.com/file/wkrsqroj7a5k3t9/BOOMPACK.zip), inside it you will find a folder named *Pack*. Drag *Pack* to your resource pack folder, and you're all set.